# Vue js not working. Simple program not showing output

Tags: vue.js

i am new to vue.js i started learning it. But this simple code is not showing any output. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vue Js | Laracast Tutorial <title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>yh{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>


<script>


    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the `title` tag:

```
<title>...</title>
```

Comment: on sorry, a silly mistake Thanks